# Reading contents of log file and calculating in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I want to implement a shell script program that provides the following functionality:

- It takes a log file as input. The log file contains the log statements with message stamp as shown below.
- The utility lists out all the actions that took more than the specified time. The time is specified in seconds from the command line.

Input:

```
#<process id> <date time> <log level> <file name> <line number> <actual message>

1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 WARN db_util.c 5928 Config file not found, using default values
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connected to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:17 ERROR log_test.c 198 Unable to setup our satellite launch system
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:21 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnected. Initialize to launch the satellite.
```

E. g. If the utility is executed by giving the input file as input and 2 seconds the performance threshold time, it should produce this output:

```
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:09 INFO db_util.c 5908 Connecting to database
1098 2007-02-28 15:23:18 INFO log_test.c 198 Reconnecting to launch the satellite
```

Comment: Just for clarification sakes, you are looking for a line to printed when the following line occurs more than 2 seconds after it (in this example although the number of seconds depends on user input)?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Answer (score 0):

With awk in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v threshold=$1 '{texttime=mktime(gensub(/-|:/," ", "g", $2" "$3))} NR>1 && texttime-prevtexttime>threshold{print prevrecord} {prevtexttime=texttime; prevrecord=$0}' $2
```

Where `$1` is your threshold time in seconds and `$2` is your log file

This awk script is:

1. setting variable `threshold` to whatever is in `$1` (`-v threshold=$1`)
2. converting the current record's date and time to a unix timestamp (`mktime(gensub(/-|:/," ", "g", $2" "$3))`) and storing that in awk variable `texttime` (`texttime=`). There may be a more elegant way of doing this, I haven't worked with date and time in `awk` before. I'm certain @edmorton will set me straight if this is the ugly way of doing it.
3. If we aren't processing the first record (`NR>1`) and the value in the `texttime` variable minus the value in the `prevtexttime` variable is greater than the value in our `threshold` variable (`texttime-prevtexttime>threshold`) then print the value in variable `prevrecord` (`print prevrecord`).
4. When done processing the record, set variable `prevtexttime` to the value in `texttime` and set the variable `prevrecord` to contents of this record `$0` (`prevtexttime=texttime; prevrecord=$0`)
5. For whatever file is specified in `$2`

Comment: Thank you so much Nevill. Amazing explanation, very clear of each command and term usage. Code is Working as expected.